# Почему значение возвращается либо в экспоненциальной форме, либо возвращается 0

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

**Первый вопрос:** почему если не указать fixed значение вернется в экспоненциальной форме?
**Второй вопрос:** почему если поставить fixed, то вернется 0, а не 2?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
const double * p1(const double n) {
    return &n;
}
const double * p2(const double n) {
    return &n;
}



int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    const double * (*pf1)(double) = p1;
    const double * (*pf2)(double) = p2;

    cout << (*pf1)(2) << ": " << fixed << *(*pf1)(2) << endl;
    cout << pf2(2) << ": " << fixed <<  *pf2(2) << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы возвращаете адрес локальной переменной. Ответ не гарантированный будет. Это значение в стеке может много раз меняться. Компилируйте с опциями предупреждений.

Comment: @AlexGlebe что значит не гарантированный ответ? И что значит компилировать с опциями предупреждений?

Comment: Адрес локальной переменной находиться обычно в стеке. После выхода из работы функции место в стеке займёт другая функция. И т.д. Всё может много раз поменяться в этой ячейке памяти. Стандарт так и говорит : неопределённое поведение.

Comment: @JustLearn Компилятор может предупреждать вас о подобных ошибках, если включить эти предупреждения в настройках. Как именно это сделать, зависит от компилятора. Например, [вот что говорит GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lWVkdg).

Comment: `const double n` уничтожается сразу после выхода из функции, параметром которой является. Так что указатель, который вы возвращаете, указывает непонятно на что (ведь переменной больше нет).